# Argument 2 of FormData.append is not an object in mozila firefox

Tags: angular, file, file-upload, multipartform-data, mozilla

sending the file to back end with help of formData.append()(appending the document details).It is working fine in google chrome.but i having facing issue in mozila and safari with this error.

[image]

Service Code:

```
  manageSingleDataWithChildModel(url: string, data: any, childData: any, docRefArea: string = ''): Observable<any> {
        this._spinnerService.show();
        this.refreshSession();
        var formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('docReferenceArea', docRefArea);
        childData.forEach((data: any) => { 
            if (data.DocumentDetails != null && data.DocumentDetails.DocContent != null && data.DocumentDetails.DocContent != "") {
                data.FileIdentifier = data.DocumentDetails.FileIdentifier;
                formData.append('files', data.DocumentDetails.DocContent, data.DocumentDetails.FileIdentifier);
                data.DocumentDetails.DocContent = null;
            }
        });
        formData.append('dataModel', JSON.stringify(data));

        let headers = new Headers(
            {
                'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
                'method': 'POST',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('BearerToken'),
            });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(url, formData, options)
            .map((res: Response) => { this._spinnerService.hide(); return HttpHelper.json(res) })
            .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/412 have you checked the link?

Answer (score 1):

docRefArea you are specifying it as string . But it is actually an object containing file details.

Try it by changing first line of your code to

```
manageSingleDataWithChildModel(url: string, data: any, childData: any, docRefArea: any = ''): Observable<any> {
```

Comment: it is string only.i just store the document reference area in db to get separate documents.